# How to send Metacoins to other accounts with truffle console and testrpc local blockchain?

Tags: truffle, testrpc

Playing around with the default project provided by truffle. I compiled the contracts with `truffle compile`.Then deployed with `truffle migrate` and after that switched to the console via `truffle console`.Any idea what the command line is for sending  for instance 10 Metacoins from default account [0] to account [1]? I set the contract object as a variable with `var meta = MetaCoin.deployed()`. After that I tried `meta.sendCoin({from:accounts[0], to:accounts[1], value: 10})` but it seems to be wrong. However I can send Ether with that command using `web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:accounts[0], to:accounts[1], value: 10})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract defines a function with the following signature:

```
function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient)
```

In order to send coins to another address you will call it like this:

```
meta.sendCoin(accounts[1], 10, {from: accounts[0]});
```

The curly braces define the account used as the "owner", you can also specify the amount of gas that can be used. The first two parameters are specific to the method signature.